# How to make multiple masked UITextView on top of a UIImageView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, uitextview, core-graphics

**NOTE:** I can't use UIView's maskView method because that changes the UITextView into a single view. My UITextViews are movable via pan, rotate and pinch gestures and maskView doesn't allow that.

Please look at these 2 pictures to understand what I am trying to achieve:

[image]

[image]

The first picture is what I already have. The background image of the tiger is a `UIImageView`. On top, I have 2 `UITextViews` "Love" and "Yolo". There can be more than 2 `UITextViews` too. I am trying to convert the first to look like the second one. Basically I want the `UITextViews` to show transparent see-through text. Everything which is not `UITextView` gets grey color.

Now note the 3rd image where the 2 `UITextViews` overlap each other. When overlapping, I want it both the `UITextViews` to be see-through like this image:

[image]

How can I achieve this effect? I am looking for guidelines on how this can be achieved.

Comment: First question: Have you been able to do this with just *one* label? Using pan, rotate and pinch gestures?

Comment: @DonMag reason why I mentioned 2 labels is because one label has a "hacky" solution. If it was only 1 label, what I was going was to add the UITextView to a container view. Then alter the drawRect of this container to color everything outside the subviews to be white and inside the subviews transparent. Then make the textview background color white and text color transparent (this part I wasn't too sure how to implement but it seems doable). However this solution won't work with more than 1 textvlews when the textviews are overlapping as the background color of the textview would still show.

Comment: @DonMag Note that I have to use UITextView and not a UILabel.

Comment: Is this because you need it editable? And... editable *while* being used as a mask?

Comment: @DonMag correct. I need it to be editable and multiline (hence can't use UILabel). And yes, it needs to be editable while being used as a mask.

Comment: Well, I think you've got some work ahead of you... To support all of that - "masking" + edit + pan / rotate / pinch gestures, etc - you will almost certainly need to have your actual text view hidden, and do all the character drawing and manipulating *as* the user types.

Comment: @DonMag I sort of have an idea on how to get this to work. I already have the edit + pan/rotate/pinch working. I first add all textviews to a container view. For masking I am thinking I can add a custom class UIImageview on the very top of everything. I can make this imagview pass through all the touches to the views underneath. Everytime user manipulates, I can use drawViewHierarchyInRect to get a combined image of the container of all textviews > convert this to mask and set this on the top most custom pass-through imageview. What do you think?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150230/discussion-between-donmag-and-pranoy-c).